# MongoDB ISODate() gives different results than Date()?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, datetime, mongodb-query

From reading the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/shell-types/#date), I was under the impression that ISODate just wrapped the Date constructor. However, I can't seem to get them to work correctly for dates very, very far in the past. For instance:

```
new Date(-8640000000000000);                          // Mon Apr 19 -271821 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
new Date(-8640000000000000).toISOString();            // -271821-04-20T00:00:00.000Z
ISODate(new Date(-8640000000000000).toISOString());   // Wed Sep 03 2719 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
```

Why do the first date, and the last date differ? I can see that I am clearly overflowing *something*, somewhere. Additionally, what are the minimum and maximum dates that Mongo can support?

**Edit:** Interestingly, this works as intended:

```
new Date( new Date(-8640000000000000).toISOString()); // Mon Apr 19 -271821 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the range part, its mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date).

> Internally, Date objects are stored as a 64 bit integer representing
>   the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970), which
>   results in a representable date range of about 290 millions years into
>   the past and future.

Let's break down what you have. I'll run everything on the mongo shell.

```
new Date(-8640000000000000); //ISODate("-271821-04-20T00:00:00Z")

new Date(-8640000000000000).toISOString(); // -271821-04-20T00:00:00.000Z

ISODate(new Date(-8640000000000000).toISOString()); //ISODate("2719-09-04T00:00:00Z")
```

Lets analyse the output from the last date. After resolving new Date(-8640000000000000).toISOString(), the output -271821-04-20T00:00:00.000Z is passed through [ISODate](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/shell/types.js#L56) function.

The previously obtained result is run through the regex (which is only expecting normal dates) in the ISO Date function.

> /(\d{4})-?(\d{2})-?(\d{2})(T
>   (:?(\d{2})(:?(\d{2}(.\d+)?))?)?(Z|([+-])(\d{2}):?(\d{2})?)?)?/

When the regex is executed against date, it results in three groups.

```
Full match  0-9 `271821-04`

Group 1.    0-4 `2718`
Group 2.    4-6 `21`
Group 3.    7-9 `04`
```

So ISODate passes these inputs to javascript [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) constructor, which will have year as 2718, month as 21 and day of the month as 4. The javascript method processes month 21 as 1 year and 9 months, so it adds the offset 1 to 2718, changing year to 2719 and month to 9 and the date is 4.

The final output date is 2719-09-04.

Answer (score 0):

Using the MongoDB Shell (embedded in meteor)

```
meteor:PRIMARY> new Date(1479424285700)
ISODate("2016-11-17T23:11:25.700Z")
meteor:PRIMARY> ISODate(new Date(1479424285700).toISOString());
ISODate("2016-11-17T23:11:25.700Z")
```

This works as expected, both return the same date.

Why were you passing `-8640000000000000` to the Date Constructor?  What date were you trying to create?

> [JavaScript Date instance that represents a single moment in time. Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
>   [objects are based on a time value that is the number of milliseconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
>   [since 1 January, 1970 UTC.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

I would suggest that passing negative values to the constructor is not covered in the specification, and you may get unexpected results if you do.

Comment: It was just a number to create some kind of minimum date (specifically, the Apr 19, -271821 date). I've since worked around it but was curious as to why this behavior happened.

Comment: Do you need dates before 1970, with millisecond precision?    I'd suggest using `new Date(0)` i.e. `ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")`

Comment: That would work, yes. But I have since changed my approach. This question is more out of curiosity about the discrepancy than trying to fix my problem.